# homebrew doesnt work on Macbook Pro with High Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I intalled homebrew to my macbook pro with high sierra version. But I doesn't work.

I always get this error.

```
Mac-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$ brew apache spark
-bash: brew: command not found
Mac-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$ brew doctor
-bash: brew: command not found
```

I was trying to install apache spark on pc thats why I wanted to use homebrew. 
But now Terminal doesnt answer any of command.

```
Mac-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$ cd
Mac-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$ touch -c .bash_profile
-bash: touch: command not found
Mac-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$
```

I always get "not found" errors. I am new to the Mac :( Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that you have the command brew in `/usr/local/bin/brew` and that it is linked to `/usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew` and that you have /usr/local/bin in your PATH